# Java while loop requiring condition variable in the end (why?)

Tags: java, variables, while-loop, conditional-statements

Why is it necessary to initialize condition variable at the end k = 1; then table++; ?

```
public class Java0521
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
        int k = 1;
        int table = 11;
      
        while (table <= 13)
        {
            while (k <= 5)
            {
                System.out.println(k + " * " + table + " = " + k * table);
                k++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            k = 1;
            table++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't increment table, then your outer while loop will loop forever. If you don't reset k, then your inner loop will only run for table=11 but not for 12 or 13 because k will already be > 5.

Comment: Nice. What I went on to try is initialize condition variable under precondition loop of the table values.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the variable outside the first while loop:

```
int k = 1;
```

after finishing the second/inner while loop the variable k would have the value 6 and would not change while still running the outer while loop and you would never again run the code of the inner while loop because k = 6 and k <= 5 is not fulfilled

Change the position of your initialization for k:

```
int table = 11;

while (table <= 13) {
    // Here the variable will be always set to 1 and
    // will only exist inside the outer while loop
    int k = 1;

    while (k <= 5) {
        System.out.println(k + " * " + table + " = " + k * table);
        k++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    table++;
}
```